# How to use map and filter together for checking two array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which looks like :

```
const tilesToShow = ['student','teacher', 'marks', 'presenty']

const response = ['student','teacher', 'internalMarks','RollNumber' 'marks','presenty']
```

Now, Here I want to show user only the tiles that are present in the `tilesToShow` array, but need to check the api response as well.

So, I have to filter the reponse, means remove the tiles from the response which are not present in the `tilesToShow` array. and then iterate the filtered array.

So How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter and includes array method for get your output, hope this will help to you

```js
const tilesToShow = ['student','teacher', 'marks', 'presenty'];

const response = ['student','teacher', 'internalMarks','RollNumber', 'marks','presenty']

console.log(response.filter((e)=> tilesToShow.includes(e)))
```

Comment: can we use reduce on this, because I want to use filter and then map on it

Comment: response.filter((e)=> tilesToShow.includes(e)).map((e)=>{
  console.log(e)  
})

you can use it above method for map after filtered the result

Answer (score 2):

```js
const response = ['student','teacher', 'internalMarks','RollNumber' 'marks','presenty']
var filteredArray = response.filter(function(item) {
    return tilesToShow.indexOf(item) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do the work for you.

```
const tilesToShow = ['student','teacher', 'marks', 'presenty']

const response = ['student','teacher', 'internalMarks','RollNumber' 'marks','presenty']

const filteredResponse = response.filter((item) => tilesToShow.includes(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Mr.Developer suggestion but keep in mind if datasets are big it's worth to consider using `Set.has` instead of ``Array.includes` due to performance. But for a few values it's not that important.